# Click iframe link and show webpage within iframe

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, iframe

hiii, i want to ask something. I want the link i click on iframe to be display within that iframe. i've already place an iframe a name and i did target the link to iframe name. but the problem is it doesnt work at all.

example:

```
   <a href="etc.com" TARGET="_theiframe">
```

we are using asp.net and sharepoint here. 
i'm a rookie and i already wasted 2days on this. could anyone help me out.

Comment: try use dynamic iframe creation and add to the page. this may will work !!!

Comment: A link (without target) inside an frame/iframe will always open inside that frame, so your problem must be somewhere else...

Comment: i hope the below solution will work ...

Comment: @Madhu it doesnt work, i've try every single "target" but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

To target the same iframe use:

```
<a href="etc.com" target="_self">
```

Comment: thanks @christophe, but it doesnt work as always. i think sharepoint is the caused of this problem